# How do I randomize a two dimensional array to have unique values in both directions?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, sorting, matrix

If I have two arrays like so:

`var lanes = {1,2,3};`

`var racers = {1,2,3,4,5};`

How can I **randomize** and **matrix** these with **unique** values in **each direction**, like so?

2 3 5

3 1 2

5 4 1

4 2 3

1 5 4

Rows do not repeat any value, and columns also do not repeat a value, with respect to themselves. Given **n** lanes and **n** racers.

I'm working on a lane rotation for a race with this criteria:

- 1-6 possible lanes
- n possible racers (10 to 20 or more)
- Each racer races exactly one time on each lane
- Each row must contain unique values (can't have the same racer on 2 lanes at a time)
- Each column must be unique (can't allow a racer to utilize a lane more than once)
- Random order

I'm using C#, and thus will likely use Linq. Regardless... I'm not sure what the logic on this should be. So far, I come up with collisions with the approaches I've tried.

Comment: Do the results need to be different each time the code runs?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Or are you just giving us a software puzzle?

Comment: I would start with [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11983/Sudoku-Solver-and-Generator) article which is a sudoku generator / solver. I think your logic is quite similar

Comment: @mjwills, yes, different every time. 

Harald, I have tried by randomizing all racers for each column (columns are unique) then looping through the rows and swapping them where there are collisions (same value cannot be in the same row twice), but often I have a collision I can't easily resolve at the end. I'm sure there are better ways.

Comment: @Selman Geç, tetsuya yamamoto, MickyD, mjwills, gnat... Closed as "too broad", really? "not enough detail", Really?  It was extremely specific and narrow in scope, super clear, and very descriptive, not to mention totally answerable.  Go easy on your trigger finger in the future.  "Too broad"  SMH.  Geez. If it was too broad and unanswerable, then I wouldn't have functional code in my project right now after community input - this is precisely what stack overflow is for.  I wish I could take points from you and give extra to Carlo Bos.  Michal Šuvada as well, very helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want, creating a 2-dim array with your random lineup for as many lanes and racers as you like, making sure no racer starts in the same lane more than once. The problem is as it's randomly assigning a lineup it may paint itself into a corner (i.e. there is no more unique value for the position given what has already been assigned in the current row and lane). In this case this solution, just tries again. I know this is not the most beautiful solution, but the collisions aren't too bad for 6 lanes and 20 players:

```
public Int32[,] GetLineup(Int32 lanes, Int32 racers)
{
    var rows = new Int32[racers, lanes];
    for (var lane = 0; lane < lanes; lane++)
    {           
        for (var racer = 0; racer < racers; racer++)
        {               
            var taken = Enumerable.Range(0, racer).Select(e => rows[e, lane]).ToList();             
            taken.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, lane).Select(e => rows[racer, e]));
            var possible = Enumerable.Range(1, racers);
            var remaining = possible.Except(taken).OrderBy(e => Guid.NewGuid());
            if (!remaining.Any())
            {
                // Failed to get a solution, try again
                return GetLineup(lanes, racers);
            }
            else
            {
                rows[racer, lane] = remaining.First();
            }
        }
    }
    return rows;
}
```

This generates something like this:

[image]

Comment: Very good.  I was really close with a similar approach, but this helps me see where I went wrong.  The recursive retry is great.

Now if the other community members weren't so trigger happy... there is nothing at all "too broad" about this question or answer, so having closed for "too broad" is completely uncalled for.  Thanks for the input.